# Error Message during Linphone Flatpak Installation

Tags: linphone

Error Message during Linphone Flatpak Installation

what do I have to do if I get this error message while executing the command:

```
flatpak --user install --from https://linphone.org/flatpak/linphone.flatpakref
```

Error:

> The Application com.belledonnecommunications.linphone/x86_64/4.1.1
>   requires the org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.6 which was not found